# Android when i pressed back from toolbar first activity is refreshed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two activity in my app in first activity I have recylerview list, when user click on any item of recycler view second activity is called.

On second activity I have toolbar with back button

```
    setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Therefore when user click on back button first activity is called but recycler view is reloaded again.

I don't want it. and if user press mobile back button that time first page is not reloaded.

So what I do to overcome from this problem any suggestion?

Regards
Manish

Comment: Did you fix it? I have same issue atm.

Answer (score 0):

put finish() on  onOptionsItemSelected, so when you click on back button the current activity will be closed and the old activity will be showed without reload again

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:               
                    finish();
                    return true;
    ...................................
```